# Two-dimensional generic array initialization

Tags: java

I tried creating a two-dimensional generic array in java. I get no compile errors, but I get an exception when running the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [[[Ljava.lang.String; to [[Ljava.lang.String;
at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
at Tabela.<init>(Tabela.java:8)
at TabelaTest.main(TabelaTest.java:4)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Tabela<T> {

    private T[][] data;

    public Tabela(Class<T[][]> c,int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.data = c.cast(Array.newInstance(c.getComponentType(), sizeX, sizeY));
    }

    public void setInfoAt(T info, int x, int y) {
        this.data[x][y] = info;
    }
    public T getObjectAt(int x, int y) {
        return this.data[x][y];
    }
}

public class TabelaTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Tabela<String> tabela = new Tabela<String>(String[][].class, 2, 2);

        tabela.setInfoAt("a", 0, 0);
        tabela.setInfoAt("b", 0, 1);
        tabela.setInfoAt("c", 1, 0);
        tabela.setInfoAt("d", 1, 1);

        System.out.println(tabela.getObjectAt(1, 0));
    }
}
```

It looks like I can't use this method for two dimensional arrays.

EDIT:

Using the method from unholysampler it works now.
The constructor was changed to:

```
public Tabela(Class<T> c,int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    this.data = (T[][])Array.newInstance(c, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

The thing is that eclipse keeps warning me about this cast (T[][]). I can supress it, but is it ok to ignore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the error message, you will see that the number of square brackets differ.

```
Cannot cast [[[Ljava.lang.String; to [[Ljava.lang.String;
            ---                      --
```

You are ending up with the extra array level because of how you are calling `Array.newInstance()`. If you wanted to just create a `String` array, you would use:

```
String[] arr = (String[])Array.newInstance(String.class, 5);
```

Notice that you pass in the base class type and the method "adds" a layer of brackets. Your call is saying that you want an array that contains instances of 2D arrays of `String`. Instead, you want to just pass in the base class normally, then specify the dimensions.

```
Array.newInstance(String.class, sizeX, sizeY);
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't really get it. For what I understand you are saying that I need to call Array.newInstance just with T instead of T[][]?

Comment: Yes. Because Array.newInstance does the job of creating the 2D array for you.

Answer (score 2):

This error is in your constructor:

```
public Tabela(Class<T[][]> c,int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.data = c.cast(Array.newInstance(c.getComponentType(), sizeX, sizeY));
}
```

- `c.getComponentType()` is actually a `T[]`.
- `Array.newInstance(Class, int...)` return an array of as much dimension as they are in a the array. You pass two values, the array is a two dimensional one.

  ```
  Array.newInstance(
    c.getComponentType(), // returns T[]
    sizeX, sizeY
  ) // returns T[][][]
  ```

Which would be a runtime equivalent to `new T[sizeX][sizeY][]` if it were possible (type erasure).

I would do that:

```
public Tabela(Class<T> c,int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.data = Array.newInstance(c, sizeX, sizeY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [`Array#newInstance(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance-java.lang.Class-int...-) states

> If `componentType` represents an array class, the number of dimensions
>   of the new array is equal to the sum of `dimensions.length` and the
>   number of dimensions of `componentType`. In this case, the component
>   type of the new array is the component type of `componentType`.

Since `componentType` is `String[]`, an array class, the number of dimensions becomes the sum of `dimensions.length`, `2`, and the number of dimensions of `componentType`, `1`, for a total of `3`.

Your call

```
Array.newInstance(c.getComponentType(), sizeX, sizeY)
```

becomes equivalent to

```
new String[2][2][]
```

You can, instead, invoke the `newInstance(Class, int)` method as

```
Array.newInstance(c.getComponentType(), sizeX)
```

to create a

```
new String[2][]
```

but you'll have to instantiate the nested arrays manually.

Or refactor your constructor parameters to implement [unholysampler's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984911/438154).